# How to loop while php to show Character Set?

Tags: php

When test this code it's will echo only `97`
I want to loop for show `97 98 99 25552 114 21734` with while loop, how can i do that ?

```
<?php
$utf8Character = 'abc提r哦';
list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($utf8Character, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
echo $ord;
?>
```

.

Then i modify to this code but not work, it's show `97 98 99 63 63 63 114 63 63 63`

```
<?php
$utf8Character = 'abc提r哦';
for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $utf8Character ); $i++ ) {   
    list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($utf8Character[ $i ], 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    echo $ord." ";
}
?>
```

How can i do for show `97 98 99 25552 114 21734` with while loop ?

Comment: What's the encoding of the document you're working in? UCS-4BE?

Comment: i use encoding UTF-8

Comment: You could try to use `mb_strlen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to iterate over the characters fails because `strlen()` actually counts the number of bytes of the string. So if you use `$utf8Character[$i]`, you will never get the Chinese character as a whole, because it consists of three bytes in UTF-8. Instead, you'll just get one of the bytes.

In order to fix it, you could count the number of characters in a multibyte setting using `mb_strlen()`. This takes the encoding into account and will return `6` in case of your string.

```php
<?php

$utf8Character = 'abc提r哦';

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($utf8Character); $i++) {

    // Get the substring consisting of a single character,
    // which might consist of multiple bytes.
    $c = mb_substr($utf8Character, $i, 1);

    // Convert the character to UCS-4BE, to get the Unicode code point
    list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($c, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));

    // Print it
    echo $ord . " ";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in the first fragment of code you posted.
Let's try to identify and fix them below:

```
$utf8 = 'abc提r哦';
// Put the UCS string into a variable for easier handling
$ucs  = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8');
echo ($ucs."\n");

// Error #1: 'N' unpacks a single 32-bit integer
print_r(unpack('N', $ucs));
// It prints:
//    Array
//    (
//        [1] => 97
//    )

// Fix: 'N*' unpacks as many 32-bit integers it can find in the input
print_r(unpack('N*', $ucs));
// It prints:
//    Array
//    (
//        [1] => 97
//        [2] => 98
//        [3] => 99
//        [4] => 25552
//        [5] => 114
//        [6] => 21734
//    )

// Error #2: list(, $ord) ignores everything starting with index 2
list(, $ord) = unpack('N*', $ucs);
var_dump($ord);
// It prints:
//     int(97)
```

The solution can be extracted from the code above:

```
$utf8 = 'abc提r哦';
$ucs  = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8');

foreach (unpack('N*', $ucs) as $ord) {
    echo($ord."\n");
}
```